# How to map multiple tables with field one to many to same table in java?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I need to solve a hibernate mapping, I have a table common that contains manytoone to the table A, B and C. (this can have only one manytoone with one table)

Then I solved it by putting the id of each table to be able to map it. 
Is there a better way to do this mapping? because i have more than 3 tables that reuse the same table

[image: SCHEMA]

Comment: So is `common` an entity that can have up to one reference to A, B and C? And each A, B and C can be referenced by multiple `common` entities, right (many-to-one implies it is so)? In that case that table structure seems fine. I can't tell about the _mapping_ because you didn't show that.

Answer (score 0):

### Common table

Contains one to many mappings

```
@Entity
    @Table(name= "common")
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
                      property  = "id",
                      scope     = Long.class)
    @DynamicInsert(true)
    @DynamicUpdate(true)
    public class Common implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 6953927535242022811L;

        @Id
        @Column(name= "id")
        private Long id = Long.parseLong(UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 8), 16);


        @OneToMany(cascade= CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy= "a_id", orphanRemoval= true )
        @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
        private List<A> aList;

        @OneToMany(cascade= CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy= "b_id", orphanRemoval= true )
        @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
        private List<B> bList;

        @OneToMany(cascade= CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy= "c_id", orphanRemoval= true )
        @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
        private List<C> cList;

        // getter and setters
    }
```

### Table A

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "a")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
                  property  = "id",
                  scope     = Long.class)
@DynamicInsert(true)
@DynamicUpdate(true)
public class A implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6953927535242022811L;

    @Id
    @Column(name= "id")
    private Long id = Long.parseLong(UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 8), 16);

    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name= "common_id")
    private Common CommonId;  //many to one is option if you required 

}
```

similar implementaion for B and C